# How to store multiple params on Session

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using like this:

```
        if(!empty($this->request->data['cd_pedido'])){
            $this->set('filtroBusca',array('cd_pedido'=>$this->request->data['cd_pedido']));
        }else if(!empty($sessaoCdPedido)){
            $this->set('filtroBusca',array('cd_pedido'=>$sessaoCdPedido));
        }

        if(!empty($this->request->data['cd_seq_pedido'])){
            $this->set('filtroBusca',array('cd_seq_pedido'=>$this->request->data['cd_seq_pedido']));
        }else if(!empty($sessaoCdSeqPedido)){
            $this->set('filtroBusca',array('cd_seq_pedido'=>$sessaoCdSeqPedido));
        }
```

And when I do :
`$this->Session->read('filtroBusca')` OR `$_SESSION['filtroBusca']`

Shows only the last checkbox selected. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Result from `$_SESSION['filtroBusca']`

`Array
    (
    [cd_pedido] => 7
     )`

Image of the checkboxs:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are erasing the array when setting it in your second 'if' condition.
You may consider using an array to buffer the data you want to put in session, then put it all at once :

```
$filtroBusca = array();
if(!empty($this->request->data['cd_pedido'])){
    $filtroBusca['cd_pedido'] = $this->request->data['cd_pedido'];
}else if(!empty($sessaoCdPedido)){
    $filtroBusca['cd_pedido'] = sessaoCdPedido;
}

//Do the same thing for the other one
```

Then put `$filtroBusca` in session :

```
$this->set('filtroBusca',$filtroBusca);
```